# How to use a main column value on the sub-query of a join

Tags: mysql

I have a table "links". Links belong to "campaigns".
Links have many "clicks", "social_clicks" and "impressions"

For each active link belonging to an active campaign I want to calculate the following rate per day: (clicks + social_clicks) / impressions

The following query works correctly. But I think querying the links table again 3 times is not optimal. I'm not able to use the link-ids from the main query, I tried to replace the sub queries with "l.id" and "t1.link_id" but it returns "Unknown column"

How can I access a column of the main query in the sub-query of a join, and is there a better way to get the result I need?

Tables:

```
links: id int, campaign_id int, status int
campaigns: id int, is_active int
clicks: id int, link_id int, created datetime
social_clicks: id int, link_id int, time datetime
impressions: id int, link_id int, created datetime
```

Query:

```
select l.id,
    sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end) as total_clicks,
    sum(case when t1.col = 'impressions' then ct else 0 end) as total_impressions,
    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end) / nullif(sum(case when t1.col = 'impressions' then ct else 0 end),0), 1000) as ctr,
    t1.dt
    from links l
inner join campaigns c
    on c.id = l.campaign_id
    and c.is_active = 1
left join
    (
    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'clicks' as col
        from clicks
        where created >= '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
        and link_id IN (SELECT l2.id from links l2 INNER JOIN campaigns c2 on c2.id = l2.campaign_id AND c2.is_active = 1 WHERE l2.status = 1)
        group by date(created), link_id

    union all

    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(time) dt, 'clicks' 
        from social_clicks
        where time >= '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
        and link_id IN (SELECT l2.id from links l2 INNER JOIN campaigns c2 on c2.id = l2.campaign_id AND c2.is_active = 1 WHERE l2.status = 1)
        group by date(time), link_id

    union all

    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'impressions' 
        from impressions
        where created > '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
        and link_id IN (SELECT l2.id from links l2 INNER JOIN campaigns c2 on c2.id = l2.campaign_id AND c2.is_active = 1 WHERE l2.status = 1)
        group by date(created), link_id

    ) t1 on t1.link_id = l.id
where l.status = 1
group by l.id, t1.dt
having total_clicks > 0
```

Comment: You should at least provide some sample data.. a fiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the inner join and left joins in the outer loop into the `union all` statements. Whether the below change will be helpful for your case?

```
select res2.id, res2.dt, sum(res2.clicks_count), sum(res2.impressions_count),
coalesce(sum(res2.clicks_count) / nullif(res2.impressions_count), 1000) as ctr,
from (
select res.id, res.dt, 
case when res.col = 'clicks' then 1 else 0 end clicks_count,
case when res.col = 'impressions' then 1 else 0 end impressions_count
from
(
select li.id, cl.link_id, date(cl.created) dt, 'clicks' as col
    from clicks cl inner join links li on cl.link_id = li.id
    inner join campaigns ca on li.campaign_id = cl.id
    where cl.created >= '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
    and ca.is_active = 1
    and li.status = 1
union all
select li.id,  cl.link_id, date(cl.created) dt, 'clicks' as col
    from social_clicks cl inner join links li on cl.link_id = li.id
    inner join campaigns ca on li.campaign_id = cl.id
    where cl.time >= '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
    and ca.is_active = 1
    and li.status = 1
union all
select li.id, im.link_id, date(im.created) dt, 'impressions' as col
    from impressions im inner join links li on im.link_id = li.id
    inner join campaigns ca on li.campaign_id = im.id
    where im.created >= '2020-11-10 00:00:00' 
    and ca.is_active = 1
    and li.status = 1
) res) res2
group by res2.id, res2.dt
having sum(res2.clicks_count) > 0;
```